# Elements moved to right of Div when they should be on newline

Tags: html, css

I'm writing some HTML pages for my personal website but I'm running into the problem that new elements aren't starting on a newline and rather starting to the right of a div containing a picture gallery.

this is easier shown than explained for me so here is a screenshot...
[image: html unwanted behavior]

As you can see I want the circled elements below the gallery div
here is the code

```
<div id="gallerydiv">
            <div class="gallery">
                <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/java1.png">
                    <img src="../AppDev images/java1.png" alt="ToDo1" width="600" height="400"/>
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Application with basic functionality</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_10.png">
                    <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_10.png" alt="ToDo10" width="600" height="400"/>
                </a>
                <div class="desc">New file prompt</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_11.png">
                    <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_11.png" alt="ToDo11" width="600" height="400"/>
                </a>
                <div class="desc">File deletion prompt</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_12.png">
                    <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_12.png" alt="ToDo12" width="600" height="400"/>
                </a>
                <div class="desc">New ticket prompt</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_13.png">
                    <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_13.png" alt="ToDo13" width="600" height="400"/>
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Ticket deletion prompt</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_14.png">
                    <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_14.png" alt="ToDo14" width="600" height="400"/>
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Complete Ticket Prompt</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_1.png">
                    <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_1.png" alt="ToDo1" width="600" height="400"/>
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Adding some tickets to complete</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_2.png">
                    <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_2.png" alt="ToDo2" width="600" height="400"/>
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Completing tickets</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_3.png">
                    <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_3.png" alt="ToDo3" width="600" height="400"/>
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Complete section functional</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_4.png">
                    <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_4.png" alt="ToDo4" width="600" height="400"/>
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Ticket formatting complete</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_7.png">
                    <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_7.png" alt="ToDo7" width="600" height="400"/>
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Adding images for buttons</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_6.png">
                    <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_6.png" alt="ToDo6" width="600" height="400"/>
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Change directory dialog</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_9.png">
                    <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_9.png" alt="ToDo9" width="600" height="400"/>
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Finished product</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p>Essentially how this app works is by storing the tickets in text files inside the working directory. Then by using tags similar to HTML the individual tickets can be pulled and stored.</p>
            <br height="500px">
            <h2>Advanced Youtube Search</h2>
        </div>
```

and the styling...

```
div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  height: 190px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

#gallerydiv {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Ive already tried spamming br and setting the gallery width to 100% percent but nothing I have tried has worked obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the same styles to the `<p>` and `<h2>` that were out of line. For example, in HTML:

```
<div class="unknown">
    <p>Essentially how this app works is by storing the tickets in text files inside the working directory. Then by using tags similar to HTML the individual tickets can be pulled and stored.</p>
    <br height="500px">
    <h2>Advanced Youtube Search</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.unknown {

      margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      float: left;
      width: 180px;
      height: 190px;
}
```

That should work...

Answer (score 0):

Add clearfix class to your div. This will move your next div to newline.

```css
    div.gallery {
        margin: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        float: left;
        width: 180px;
        height: 190px;
        border: 5px solid red;
    }

    div.gallery:hover {
        border: 1px solid #777;
    }

    div.gallery img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    div.desc {
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #gallerydiv {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    div.clearfix::after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: table;
    }
    
    div.mydiv {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="gallerydiv"  class="clearfix">
        <div class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/java1.png">
                <img src="../AppDev images/java1.png" alt="ToDo1" width="600" height="400"/>
            </a>
            <div class="desc">Application with basic functionality</div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_10.png">
                <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_10.png" alt="ToDo10" width="600" height="400"/>
            </a>
            <div class="desc">New file prompt</div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_11.png">
                <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_11.png" alt="ToDo11" width="600" height="400"/>
            </a>
            <div class="desc">File deletion prompt</div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_12.png">
                <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_12.png" alt="ToDo12" width="600" height="400"/>
            </a>
            <div class="desc">New ticket prompt</div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_13.png">
                <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_13.png" alt="ToDo13" width="600" height="400"/>
            </a>
            <div class="desc">Ticket deletion prompt</div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_14.png">
                <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_14.png" alt="ToDo14" width="600" height="400"/>
            </a>
            <div class="desc">Complete Ticket Prompt</div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_1.png">
                <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_1.png" alt="ToDo1" width="600" height="400"/>
            </a>
            <div class="desc">Adding some tickets to complete</div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_2.png">
                <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_2.png" alt="ToDo2" width="600" height="400"/>
            </a>
            <div class="desc">Completing tickets</div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_3.png">
                <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_3.png" alt="ToDo3" width="600" height="400"/>
            </a>
            <div class="desc">Complete section functional</div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_4.png">
                <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_4.png" alt="ToDo4" width="600" height="400"/>
            </a>
            <div class="desc">Ticket formatting complete</div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_7.png">
                <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_7.png" alt="ToDo7" width="600" height="400"/>
            </a>
            <div class="desc">Adding images for buttons</div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_6.png">
                <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_6.png" alt="ToDo6" width="600" height="400"/>
            </a>
            <div class="desc">Change directory dialog</div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="../AppDev images/Screenshot_9.png">
                <img src="../AppDev images/Screenshot_9.png" alt="ToDo9" width="600" height="400"/>
            </a>
            <div class="desc">Finished product</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mydiv">
        <p>Essentially how this app works is by storing the tickets in text files inside the working directory. Then by using tags similar to HTML the individual tickets can be pulled and stored.</p>
        <br height="500px">
        <h2>Advanced Youtube Search</h2>
    </div>
```